# as soon as i put cursor( hover) on menu my web page content moves ? In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web, hover

as soon as i put cursor hover on menu my web page content moves ? In  Asp.net 
[image]
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a higher z-index on the menu so it will be above the other content and not interfere.

```css
#main-menu {
z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: i am trying to add code but site prevents the code it shows lot of suggestions